# Is it possible to create a folder in Google Drive using Postman/HTTP Requests?

Tags: google-drive-api, postman

I'm using Google's own Postman Collection with a built in request called "Create folder", which sends a post request with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files, but in the body it forces me to attach a file to upload and doesn't create any folders. I've tried changing the body from the default form data into form-urlencoded as well as passing it a raw json body with:

```json
{
    "name": "folderName",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

But in the end it just uploads the text and doesn't create a folder. In the google api documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) they only have Python/Java/Node examples so is creating a folder in google drive with postman even possible?

Comment: Hi, I found some Google API reference that maybe it will be helpful https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Comment: In your question, can you link the Google Postman Collection and post the full request that Postman is sending? Its definitely possible. It may just be that the endpoint you are using is not `/upload/drive...` it is just `/drive/...` no upload as upload is for files with content and folders have no content.

Comment: Is [this](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6034746/SzYaUd8j) the collection you are referring to? If so, it's not Google's, and in the docs under "Create Folder" it says you have to attach a file to create a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using the API explorer, I was able to create a folder at the top level without uploading a file. A screenshot is at the bottom of this answer.

I had F12 dev tools open at the time, so I was able to copy the complete request. Here it is as a curl command. I suspect many of the request headers are unnecessary but I don't have proof.

Since it can be done with the API explorer and with curl, I have every reason to expect it can work with Postman. But again, I have not tried personally.

```
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json&key=AIza...REDACTED...cDM' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' 
  --compressed 
  -H 'X-ClientDetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows)&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%3B%20rv%3A81.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F81.0' 
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29....REDACTED....7AI' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
  -H 'X-JavaScript-User-Agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' 
  -H 'X-Origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' 
  -H 'X-Referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' 
  -H 'X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable: base64' 
  -H 'Origin: https://content.googleapis.com' 
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
  -H 'Referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.whfkM83gL4c.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNEkBkMjISSZ4ljrkdiuB2RlTeIDA%2Fm%3D__features__' 
  --data-raw '{"name":"foobar","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}'
```

[image: screenshot of API explorer]